# How to Redirect Https to Http for certain url

Tags: .htaccess, https

I am redirecting my site to `https://` from `htaccess`
what i need to do now for specific url like below it will redirect to `http://`

`mydomain.com/index.php?view=news`

I have tried with below but it is not working
all the pages are redirecting to https://

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index.php?view=news [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

how can i redirect specific url to http and others to https

Comment: Did you tried hard refresh and cache clearing?

Comment: yes i am trying everytime clearing the cache but not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the question mark `?` in your `THE_REQUEST` regex pattern since its a regex special character

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index.php\?view=news [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```